# Windows forms application WM_USER message receiving

Tags: winforms, winapi

I am developing Windows forms application using visual studio C++, and want to sendmessage from a thread to the window (WM_USER message), however I can't find out where to place the code (Studio does it automatically) for receiving that message. How to do it?
 Is it the right approach in windows forms application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the [`WndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) method of your form. In that method you can implement any special handling you need for any Windows messages delivered to your form's window.

Take care to follow the documentation to the letter:

> **Notes to Inheritors**
>
> Inheriting controls should call the base class's
>   WndProc method to process any messages that they do not handle.